# Set 'income this month' as standard report on the Google AdSense homepage

Tags: google-adsense, reporting

When I go to https://www.google.com/adsense/app#home
I see income 'Today so far', 'Yesterday', 'Last 7 days' and 'Last 28 days'

How can I show income 'this month' as a report on this page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the homepage in Google Adsense.   You are stuck with whatever they show you.

Google has changed the AdSense home page several times in the last few years.   It used to show the number you are looking for, but it no longer does.   During the process for the home page redesign, they solicited feedback from AdSense users.   I was one of the ones that asked for 7 and 28 day views because they make the comparison periods work well.

I would also like to see a total of this months earnings somewhere on the home page.   Maybe it could be "earnings not yet finalized" and appear without the comparison period near the "finalized earnings".

The easiest way to get the data is to pull it from performance reports right now.